# Am I a wizard? An led lights up when my fingers get close

Tags: arduino

I was writing some simple code involving a tilt ball switch, but it didn't end up working right. I messed around with the inputs and outputs and eventually I learned that when I put my fingers near the input pin, the built-in led lit up. I didn't even have to touch anything. Are the input pins just really sensitive to an electric or magnetic field in my fingers?

Here is the code that I was running: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PlV4.png)

When the led built-in was lighting up I only had the Arduino hooked up to a power source. The most logical thing that I can come up with (which is probably wrong) is that my fingers are magnetized which creates a magnetic flux which induces a current. So basically I'm Magneto until somebody tells me what is actually happening.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics.

Comment: Please never post code as am image. Instead copy - paste as text from your code editor to the question editor and format it as code (with the '{}' button)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not qualified to answer whether or not you are Magneto.

As for the Arduino, try adding a resistor between Pin 8 and Ground.
That should help to drain the phantom signal that your mutant powers are generating.

Comment: I am qualified: Everybody is Magneto :)  And everybody is a resistor and a capacitor and...